# Is there a way to set JSON object to elasticsearch index as key-value pairs via AsyncLogger using log4j2-elasticsearch-hc appender

Tags: elasticsearch, log4j2

I am using the Using log4j2-elasticsearch-hc appender (asyncLogger) to directly write my logs to ElasticSearch. My log is basically Log POJO (i.e. JSON). However; when I say; Logger.info(logPojoInstance); the entire instance gets stringified against a property named "message" as opposed to being key-value pairs. Please look at the ElasticSearch output in the screenshot below :[image]

What can be done so that the LogDTO is displayed in key-value as opposed to a stringified / serialized json adjacent to message....I want to be able to query these logs which wont be possible in this scenario.

I tried the VirtualProperty approach but as I am using AsyncLogger the value does not seem to set.

```
<VirtualProperty name="ctxVariable" value="$${ctx:myFavouriteVariable:-notSupportedWithAsyncLogger}" dynamic="true" />
```

Any leads please let me know !

Also pasting the log4j2.xml for reference :

Answer (score 1):

You can use the official [JSON Template Layout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html) in combination with `log4j2-elasticsearch-hc`. JTL is the most feature-rich and customizable JSON-based layout in the wild and can render non-`String` messages. See [the `message` event template resolver docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html#event-template-resolver-message) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like not possible currently : https://github.com/rfoltyns/log4j2-elasticsearch/issues/91